# How to decompress the gzip data received by ajax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hellow!

There is a problem: php sends data compressed with gzdeflate():

```
$string=gzdeflate($string,9);
echo $string;
```

In the browser pako.js is included and the following runs:

```
var rsp=rst.responseText;
rsp=pako.inflate(rsp);
```

But the console says: "Uncaught unknown compression method".

(The ajax code works well without compression and pako.inflate.)

If I use base64_encode()

```
$string=base64_encode($string);
```

or use gzdeflate() instead of gzencode(), I have the same problem.

How to unpack the gzip data in javascript?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Send the header `Content-Encoding: deflate` and the browser will decompress it automatically.

Comment: As usual, Barmar is right, But it would better yet to use the ob_gz_hander() which will check what the browser supports, send the appropriate header and apply the appropriate compression.

Comment: Better yet, enable compression in nginx/apache/whatever and then _everything_ gets compressed and has proper headers added.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with php, so I kinda struggled with this problem even after reading the comments here, so I thought to post a minimal working solution in php:

```
$response = gzdeflate('My data', 9, ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE);

header('Content-Encoding: deflate');
echo $response;
```

No need to use pako then, the data will be decompressed by the browser.